# Matrix Table now show repeating values Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I would like to ask you advice on how to show these data in matrix that does not show as repeating values :

[image]

Here is the matrix I created :

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you don't want repeating. Do you not want Months repeating?